# Need to disable EventLogging which is enabled default by UseWindowsService()

Tags: .net, logging, windows-services

I have below code which I have used to run my windows app as a service using UseWindowsService() (Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices.dll) but this method by default enables EventLogging and I want to disable the event logging as I am logging those messages to a text file using Serilog. Please let me know how can I disable the event logging feature which is set by UseWindowsService() without affecting Serilog logging and Console logging functionalities.

Please note that my application is running on .Net 4.7.2 framework.

```
    private static IHostBuilder ConfigureRequest()
    {
      var host = new HostBuilder()
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices(service =>
        {
          service.AddSingleton(BuildLogger);
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((context, factory) =>
        {
          factory.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
          factory.AddConsole();
          factory.AddSerilog(
            factory.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<Serilog.ILogger>(),
            dispose: true
          );
        });

      return host;
    }
```